# Mocha Test: Warning Promise with no error callback

Tags: typescript, promise, mocha.js

I'm writing a unit test using Mocha with Typescript, I'm quite new to promises but I think I've ran into something peculiar. I have a unit test like so

```
test("Hello world command exists", function(done) {
    let cmds = vscode.commands.getCommands(true)
    cmds.then(
        ids => {
            let containsCmd = ids.indexOf("extension.sayHello")
            assert.notEqual(containsCmd, -1)
            done()
        },
        err => {
            assert.fail()
            done(err)
        }
    )
```

The test runs fine but I am getting a warning that is bugging me. `WARNING: Promise with no error callback`. I understand that this is because `cmds.then()` returns another promise object but I actually don't want to do anything else with that promise object because I'm asserting on the first one. Right now I've found myself adding this:

```
.then(() => { return }, () => { return })
```

After the last statement but I don't think it's a very elegant solution is there a more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but you shouldn't thrown exceptions in an onRejected handler (`assert.fail()`) *without* continuing the promise chain. This will lead to exceptions being swallowed, and `done(err)` not being called.

Instead, you can rely on the fact that Mocha supports promises out of the box and will handle any (unexpected) rejections:

```
test("Hello world command exists", function() {
  let cmds = vscode.commands.getCommands(true)
  return cmds.then(ids => {
    let containsCmd = ids.indexOf("extension.sayHello")
    assert.notEqual(containsCmd, -1)
  })
})
```

If the assertion fails, or if `cmds` is rejected entirely, the test will fail.